# How to perform a spatial join of point and polygon layers in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, attribute-joins

I have a point dataset representing households that I want to associate with a parcel layer (i.e. assign its parcel_id). With ArcMap, I could spatially join the polygons to the points and specify that the join have a certain search radius and use the nearest polygon.

I wish to perform this with postgres and was wondering what the most prudent way of doing this was. I can't use ST_contains because points fall on streets and not on actual parcels. In stead of ST_contains, is there another function allowing for proximity checks?

```
update households h set parcel_id = p.parcel_id 
from parcels p where ST_contains(p.the_geom, h.xy);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For what you want to accomplish, I think [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) would work. From the PostGIS site documentation:

> ST_DWithin — Returns true if the geometries are within the specified
>   distance of one another. For geometry units are in those of spatial
>   reference and For geography units are in meters and measurement is
>   defaulted to use_spheroid=true (measure around spheroid), for faster
>   check, use_spheroid=false to measure along sphere.

Comment: This could probably work, but the trick is to set a proper search threshold. Set it too high and I get more than one match, set it too low and I get none. Or set it high and discard the extra match records.