# How can you join attributes from polygons to points which are within the polygon feature using PostgreSQL and PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, spatial-join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to perform a spatial join of point and polygon layers in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20450/how-to-perform-a-spatial-join-of-point-and-polygon-layers-in-postgis)

I don't know how to solve my actual problem.

I have polygons and points (some points are located in the polygons) and I want to add the polygon attributes to the points when they are inside the polygons.

Does anybody has an idea how to do this?

Comment: What you want to do is called a spatial join. It's already covered in this question. [How to perform a spatial join of point and polygon layers in PostGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20450/how-to-perform-a-spatial-join-of-point-and-polygon-layers-in-postgis)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the st_within statement. So something like:

```
select * from point p1, polygon p2 where st_within (p1.geom, p2.geom)
```

More information on the [postgis website](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Within.html).