# Spatial join points and polygons in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, sql

I have two spatial data sets in PostGIS tables:

1. polygon grid (table: grid_jakarta)
2. points (table:tweets)

For each point in 'tweets', I want to retrieve the reelvant attribute 'gridID' from the spatially corresponding polygon contained in 'grid_Jakarta'. Then I want to generate a new table that holds both. I assume this is a spatial join?

This is the query I have tried (based on a tutorial: https://datamodelprototype.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/linking-point-data-to-polygon-data-using-qgis-or-postgis-sql/), but to no avail:

```
SELECT pts.*, grid.gid as gridID
FROM "tweets" AS pts
INNER JOIN "grid_jakarta" AS grid
ON st_within(pts.location, grid.the_geom) AS result
```

Note, I need to use PostGIS due to the large quantity of points and polygons.

I have also checked previous QAs (e.g [How to perform a spatial join of point and polygon layers in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20450/how-to-perform-a-spatial-join-of-point-and-polygon-layers-in-postgis)), but these aren't trying to achieve exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most natural way to do this is with a cross join, using [ST_Contains](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) in the where clause to restrict the result. ST_DWithin checks for things within a certain distance of any geometry, not for containment, as you need.

```
CREATE TABLE grid_tweets AS
SELECT pts.*, grid.gid as gridID
FROM 
    "tweets" AS pts, "grid_jakarta" grid
WHERE ST_Contains( grid.the_geom, pts.location)
```

You will want to make sure that you have a spatial index on the grid table. You will probably end up doing a full table scan on the tweets table anyway, so a spatial index on that is unlikely to help.

Comment: Thankyou. This approach worked perfectly. Thanks for the tip about spatial indexing. For those others that are new to this, a good explanation here: http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html